# css for jqueryui modal dialog box

Tags: jquery, css, user-interface, dialog, modal-dialog

So I have had to modify the jqueryui modal dialog to make it comply with company standards. 
I'm having a little cross browser issue with the floats and widths of the input labels. Here is the sample website:

```
http://inetwebdesign.com/PartnerPortal/update-my-company-information2.html
```

Here is the style I am currently using:

```
    <style>
    div#dialog-form label{
    float:left;vertical-align:top;
    }
    div#dialog-form input{
    float:right;
    width:270px;
   vertical-align:top;
    }
    div#dialog-form select{
    float:right;
    }
    div#dialog-form select option{
    float:right;
    }
    </style>
```

In `Firefox,` the input boxes show the way they should, in `IE9` the input is about 3 pixels longer, in Chrome about 3pixels shorter, and in Safari about 10 pixels or more longer. To check the style click on "`new address`" next to the last textarea box and the jqueryui modal dialog box should pop up.

Does anyone have any conditional code to handle these discrepancies?

Comment: Are you using a reset style sheet?

Comment: Thanks mazzzzz for responding. The main page is using a reset style sheet yes.

Comment: It looks like none of your includes (be it javascript or css) are loading? Why are you trying to connect to port 90 with domain: daldevwebcms2?

Comment: Hi mazzzzz. That's one of the dev sites we are using. I will try to pull those files off that server and place them locally. Thanks.

Comment: Just a thought, I couldn't access them, so maybe you couldn't access them all either?  idk, haha, your architecture, not mine.

Comment: Thanks for responding mazzzzz. Yup, its the architecture messing me up.

Comment: Alright, you should probably close the question then.  Should be right below the tags under your question.

Answer (score 0):

U could also use the jquery themeroller 
http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/

That might come in handy :)